# is there any problem with my server

Tags: linux, munin, connections, failed

Below is a Munin Service Monitor screenshot for netstat by day which have a lot of failed connection.
so I need to know is this a serious issue?

[image]

Comment: Is it a serious issue? Maybe. It depends entirely on what those failed connections are/were.

Comment: It should not be downvoted - it is a valid question on how to read this brain-dead graph.

Comment: Was it downvoted?

Comment: Agreed syneticon-dj, I upvoted just to make up for that idiocy. People are way too judgmental here.

Comment: @joeqwerty *your* reputation is surely enough to have the "view vote counts" privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of "failed" connections in your graph is rather low. For some unfathomable reason, munin developers chose a logarithmic scale for graphing, but reading the y-axis you should see that the values for "failed" are somewhere between 1*10^(-2)/s and 1*10^(-1)/s, which expands to 3 - 30 failed connections within the 5 minute collection interval. Compared to the value of your successfully "established" connections which are graphed with a maximum of 230/s (or roughly 70,000 connections within the 5-min-interval) this is a rather low value.

So probably this is not a serious issue, unless of course you are investigating a particular problem and want to rule out failed connection setups as a possible cause.